# run the disk space checking script in linux without login

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I wrote a script for checking the disk space in the linux machine using shell script when i am login.
       Now if i am not login in that machine but i need an alert if the disk space is more than the threshold (ex:80) means how can i check?

1.Using ssh (remote command execution)
2.Run as a background script.

Which one is more efficient?

or is there any other ideas to do this?

I do not want to do any kind of login directly/indirectly. ie. I even don't want to use ssh keygen to store keys. It should work like the webpages, with any new systems also but without any kind of security tuning

Pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) program is a good place to start.  It is available on any Linux system, and can be setup to run programs at regular intervals.  If the program produces error messages, those are normally emailed to the account which create the cron job.

Comment: Can i run my script using this cron job?

Comment: Probably.  If the script requires some interaction, that can make it hard.  But "most" useful scripts of the sort you are describing can be run in cron.

Comment: ok.  A sample script would make it easier to offer specific advice on how to use cron.

Answer (score 0):

Script for checking the disk usage and cpu usage

```
ALERT=60
```

df command is used to check the list of disks available and their attributes.Here we get the Filesystem information and take name of the file system and usage of the file 
system through awk command.Next for getting the value we cut the % symbol and get the interger only.Then we check the condition for Alert Message.

```
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem'  | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output; do
usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}'| cut -d '%' -f1 )
partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then
echo  "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep $partition $HOSTNAME"
fi
done
```

This is the script i have written for checking the disk space.
Then i gave crontab -e command in the terminal add the script to the file.Now the new cron job is assigned.i set the cronjob to be executed for every 1 hour to monitor the disk space check.

So,Now i can't able to get the message notification.If i am not logged in in that machine,How to get the information about the disk space check?

Is there any thing needs to improve in the script?